# Live Stream Video Not Playing On Some Android Versions, HTML5 Video Not Found

Tags: html, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming, flowplayer

> I am working on website which provides live streams....
>   I am using CDNSun services....I have used JwPlayer, Currently i am using FlowPlayer HTML5... I have setup my code through CDNSUN help section(How To).... The live streams and other video files are playing perfectly on Pcs,  maximum number of browsers, iOS,Galaxy S4 etc But the problem is they are not playing on some android versions 3-4...

**My view Code:**

```
        <meta name="description" content="Euro Az Channel live at euroaz.tv">
        <link rel="stylesheet"href=
       "http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.5.2/skin/minimalist.css">
        <style>
            #mediaplayer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>

        <div id="mediaplayer"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery
     /1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.5.2/
    flowplayer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#mediaplayer').flowplayer({
             'live': true,
             'rtmp': 'rtmp://837971203.r.cdnsun.net/837971203/_definst_',
            'playlist': [[
           {
                              'flash': 'mystream'
           },
          {
          'mpegurl': 'http://abcdspaceonelr.com/837971203/_definst_/mystream/playlist.m3u8'
           }
           ]],
          'splash':true,
          'poster': 'cover_image.jpeg',
          'embed': false
          });
          });
        </script>
```

**The error i am seeing again and again is**

> "HTML5:Video Not Found" ,,, as video playing fine except some android phones....may be flash problem,, i don't know...

[Live Stream Here](http://euroaz.tv/EuroAzLive)
Please if someone can help, Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the `HTML5:Video Not Found` error on the link you provided when there's no Flash plugin available (Chrome on **Android 4.4.4**!). For some reason it insists to play it with Flash and doesn't fall back to the HLS URL which can be played natively.

One thing you could do with your embedding example is to reverse the order of the playlist items and put the HLS URL first. According to the [example on the Flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org/docs/setup.html#empty-container) docs they are in picking-order:

```
 playlist: [
         // a list of type-url mappings in picking order
         [
            { mpegurl: "http://example.com/video.m3u8" },
            { webm:    "http://example.com/video.webm" },
            { mp4:     "http://example.com/video.mp4" }
         ]
      ],
```

Anyway, you should use `HLS` as its widely supported (Android 4.x, occasional hiccups depending on version). For older devices you might need `RTP/RTSP`.